# Why can I not grab certain tags using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get the number of votes on quora answers(In this specific case the number "13"):

[Image of the element I want to grab:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scoHP.png)

What I have tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = "https://www.quora.com/Have-you-ever-made-your-dad-cry-If-so-how-and-what-did-you-do-afterwards"

res = requests.get(url1)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")
z = soup.find('span', {'class': 'count'})
print(z)
```

I don't get anything. I have tried to get the parent tag but that didn't work either.
However, this work on most other sites. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to be registered in Quora first, otherwise you [won't get directly](http://screencast.com/t/yHAag3Fn) the information you're looking for, make sure that information is available to you first

Comment: @DhruvPathak Why I don't see the number of upvotes then?

Answer (score 0):

You have the picture but not the data structure, so this may or may not be correct -- But based on previous BeautifulSoup issues try this:

```
z = soup.find('span', class_='count')
```

Depending on the content, print z probably won't work. It'll probably print an object identifier. print(z.text) is more likely to work